# How to click ignore every time I get the pop-up "Your computer was restarted becuase of a problem"?

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to create an automation for the following pop-up in macOS that either clicks on the Ignore button or closes it.

[image: mac]

I tried using pyautogui and applescript but it's not helping
Applescript.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SystemUIServer"
        set errorWindow to first window whose subrole is "AXStandardWindow" and description contains "error message"
        tell errorWindow
            click button "Ignore" of group 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```